# ECDH Public Key Recovery - Determine if valid key exists from just signature and message

Tags: signature, diffie-hellman, dsa

If I have just the (r,s,v) values of the signature and the message hash, what is the most efficient way to determine if a valid public key exists?

I do not need to know the public key, just that the signature and message hash recover to a public key.

Lets say with the notation:

- , are the values from the signature.
- ℎ is the hash of the message being verified
- is the public key
- is the group generator
- || is the x-coordinate of the point
- {,′} are the two curve points with x-coordinate

The recovery would be:

$$P \ \overset{?}{=} r^{-1}s\{R, R'\} - r^{-1}hG$$

My question is if there is a fast way of determining whether P exists, without doing the full expensive calculations to determine P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"My question is if there is a fast way of determining whether P exists, without doing the full expensive calculations to determine P."

I believe that you could check whether $r$ is a valid nonzero $x$ coordinate; that is, whether it is a part of a solution to curve equation (e.g. if your curve is in Weierstrass form with characteristic > 3, you'd check whether $x^3 + ax + b$ is a Quadratic Residue).

If it is (and if it is nonzero), then yes, you could perform the operations to recover $P$, and it would come up with two valid points, and so that's your answer.

Comment: I am using the secp256k1 curve, so the equation is y² = x³+7

If I calculate x³+7m, is there a fast way of determining it is a valid quadratic residue?

Would the fastest way be ((x³+7m)^((−1)/2)) mod , where m is 2^256-2^32-977

Comment: @SyedJafri: actually, it'd be $x^3+7$, not $x^3+7m$.  In any case, you could compute that, or compute the Legendre symbol (which might not be significantly faster, and is certainly more obscure).

Comment: Just to be clear, if I calculate  x³+7, I would have a result, but I still need to use Euler's criterion to further check that the result is in-fact a quadratic residue right?

Comment: @SyedJafri: that is correct...